# Getting the value of select option

Tags: php, select

I have a dropdown list with 2 option (LOCAL and IMPORT). The option for Import is working and I can get the value and echo the **$refnumb** (IMCK2016-0000001). But when I select LOCAL I get the same value of **$refnumb** **IMCK2016-0000001** instead of **LOCCK2016-0000001**. Please help me find what's wrong with my code. Thanks.

```
<table id='tblselect' class=normal2 style='font-size:0.6em;'>
<tr><th align='right'>Shipment Type: </th>       
<!--<tr><td><input type='submit' name='lookup_master' value='COPY' /></td></tr>-->
<?php $shipmenttype = array("0"=>"Please select...", "LOC"=>"LOCAL", "IM"=>"IMPORT");?>

<td><b><select name='shiptype' id='shiptype'>
    <?php foreach($shipmenttype as $keyname=>$ship_type):?>

        <?php 
            $selected ="";
                    $shiptype = $_POST['shiptype'];
                    if($keyname == $shiptype): $selected =" selected"; endif;
        ?>                    
            <option value="<?php echo $keyname;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $ship_type;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
</select></b></td></tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<?php


$site = dbGetConfig("sitecode");
$dbnextID = dbNextID($keyname);

if($site=="CKI") {
$site="CK".date("Y");
}
if($site=="PQI") {
$site="PQ".date("Y");
}
$refnumb = $keyname.$site."-".str_pad($dbnextID,7,0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```

Reference Number:

```
<input type='text' name='ref_no1' id='ref_no1' value="<?php echo $refnumb ?>" readonly />
```

Here's the function for dbNextID.

```
function dbNextID($key) {
$sql1 = "insert into key_master (keyname) values (:keyname)";
$sql2= "update key_master set id = id + 1 where keyname = :keyname";
$sql3 = "select id from key_master where keyname = :keyname";

$conn = dbConnect(); 
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);

$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt1->execute(array(':keyname' => $key));
$stmt2->execute(array(':keyname' => $key));
$stmt3->execute(array(':keyname' => $key)); 
$value = $stmt3->fetchColumn(0);
$conn->commit();
$conn=null;

return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$keyname` is getting set inside your for loop. When you are printing out `$refnumb`, you are referencing `$keyname` outside the loop. This means that you will get the last element in `$shipmenttype` is "IM").

To fix this, you will need to track the selected value.

```
<table id='tblselect' class=normal2 style='font-size:0.6em;'>
<tr><th align='right'>Shipment Type: </th>       
<!--<tr><td><input type='submit' name='lookup_master' value='COPY' /></td></tr>-->
<?php $selectedValue = 0; $shipmenttype = array("0"=>"Please select...", "LOC"=>"LOCAL", "IM"=>"IMPORT");?>

<td><b><select name='shiptype' id='shiptype'>
    <?php foreach($shipmenttype as $keyname=>$ship_type):?>

        <?php 
            $selected ="";
                    $shiptype = $_POST['shiptype'];
                    if($keyname == $shiptype) $selected =" selected";$selectedValue = $keyname; endif;
        ?>                    
            <option value="<?php echo $keyname;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $ship_type;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
</select></b></td></tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<?php


$site = dbGetConfig("sitecode");
$dbnextID = dbNextID($selectedValue);

if($site=="CKI") {
$site="CK".date("Y");
}
if($site=="PQI") {
$site="PQ".date("Y");
}
$refnumb = $selectedValue.$site."-".str_pad($dbnextID,7,0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```

Comment: Hi @James, I'm getting 0CK2016-0000001.

Comment: If you're getting 0, then it means ($keyname == $shiptype) is never true.

Comment: How come it's 0 if I select one of the option? so what should I do?

Comment: Do you want this value to update, when you select from the dropdown? Currently this value isn't updated. It renders once on the server and doesn't update. You will need to use Javascript to update the value.  Here is some references to learn what you need  to do... Might be a fair bit of learning, though! :) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir_O2MhqHKAhVKmJQKHfE5BxUQFgg0MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fajax%2F&usg=AFQjCNFmLRm6sp49xDSldbev20v5BclZ7w&sig2=RVYEcNeLbX6zdgXeM4QJNA

Comment: No, I just want to get the value LOC and IM based on the selected option to process a different code.

Comment: Do you want the client's web browser (Javascript) to run code or the server (PHP)? If you want the server to, you will either need to: refresh the page, or send an AJAX request. Either way, you will most likely need to write some javascript code to help you along the way. PHP has no "power" once the page has been sent to your web browser.